# Array output structure

Tags: java, arrays

Why the output of this code is

```
island = Fiji
island = Cozumel
island = Bermuda
island = Azores
```

Why the output starts from Fiji island , instead of "Bermuda"? Bermuda have 0 element in array . Can you please point me why my output have such specific order.

```
public class TestArrays {
public static void main (String[] args){
    int y = 0;
    int[] index = new int [4];
    index[0] = 1;
    index[1] = 3;
    index[2] = 0;
    index[3] = 2;


    String[] islands = new String[4];
    islands[0] = "Bermuda";
    islands[1] = "Fiji";
    islands[2] = "Azores";
    islands[3] = "Cozumel";

    int ref;
    while ( y < 4){
        ref = index[y];
        System.out.print("island = ");
        System.out.println(islands[ref]);
        y = y + 1;

    }

}
```

Comment: As i understand it should be like : Bermuda / Fiji / Azores / Cozumel
Each time by adding y+1;

Comment: That would be the case when printing `islands[y]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index is ordered as {1, 3, 0, 2}

```
int[] index = new int [4];
index[0] = 1;
index[1] = 3;
index[2] = 0;
index[3] = 2;
```

So it will print islands[1], islands[3], islands[0], islands[2]

```
String[] islands = new String[4];
islands[0] = "Bermuda";
islands[1] = "Fiji";
islands[2] = "Azores";
islands[3] = "Cozumel";
```

Fiji, Cozumel, Bermuda, Azores

Answer (score 1):

It's quite simple:

```
ref = index[y];
```

The above line outputs `ref` as **1**, since `index[y]` results **1** when `y` was **0**.

Therefore,

```
ref = 1  //index[0] = 1;
```

Now, the line below:

```
System.out.println(islands[ref]);
```

Outputs:

> island = Fiji

because `ref` was **1** and `islands[ref]` stands *Fiji* as in:

```
islands[1] = "Fiji";
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it is printing out that way because you are telling it to.

You set up your index like this

```
int[] index = new int [4];
    index[0] = 1;
    index[1] = 3;
    index[2] = 0;
    index[3] = 2;
```

and then call

```
ref = index[y];
        System.out.print("island = ");
        System.out.println(islands[ref]);
        y = y + 1;
```

The value in `index[y]` is why you are printing it out in that order.

index[0] is 1, so when you call `System.out.println(islands[ref]);` you are calling `System.out.println(islands[1]);`, which is `Fiji`.

Answer (score 0):

In the call island[ref] for y=0,1,2,3. The calls are

```
island[index[0]] = island [1] = "Fiji"
island[index[1]] = island [3] = "Cozumel"
island[index[2]] = island [0] = "Bermuda"
island[index[3]] = island [2] = "Azores"
```

You have basically changed the index call for island from your index array.

Answer (score 0):

```
    int ref;
    while ( y < 4){
        System.out.println(y); (1)
        ref = index[y];
        System.out.println(ref); (2)
        System.out.print("island = ");
        System.out.println(islands[ref]);
        y = y + 1;

    }
```

**Iteration # 01**

Statement (1) will produce 0 since `y` is 0, and statement (2) will produce 1 because `index[0]` has 1 stored in it. And `islands[1]` has **Fiji**

**Iteration # 02**

Statement (1) will produce 1 since `y` is 1, and statement (2) will produce 3 because `index[1]` has 3 stored in it. And `islands[3]` has **Cozumel**

Iterating over the while loop like this until `y < 4` for each index will help you see, why the generated output is like the way, it is.